# can't get entire innerhtml of an element

Tags: jquery

i want to get inner html of `li.insert_option`  and put it in a table

my html is something like this

```
  <li class="insert_option">
        <tr  dir="rtl" >
        <td style="text-align:left ; background-color:#CCC"><?php echo $pf->title; ?> </td>
        <td style="text-align:left ; background-color:#CCC">  <input name="id[<?php echo $pf->id; ?>]" type="text" value="" /></td>
        </tr>
     </li>
```

my jquery code is

```
$('#pack_adder_serviceselect').change(function(){
    $('#new_cat #option_table').html('');

    var id = $(this).val();
    var io = $('#pack_fildset_'+id).find('.insert_option');

    $.each(io , function(){
        $('#new_cat #option_table').append($(this).html());
        console.log($(this).html());
    })
})
```

here is what my consol log :

```
    xxx
      <input name="id[3]" value="" type="text">
```

where is the `tr` and `td` ?

Comment: Could have something to do with the fact that <tr> is not a valid tag inside <li> tags.

Comment: `tr` = TABLE-Row, `td` = TABLE-Data .... where is your `table` ? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your markup is invalid, browsers do not render `tr` and `td` elements when there is no `table` wrapper element, so there is no `tr`/`td` element in the DOM to be selected by jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the outerhtml() function of jquery.
Also, look into calling parent().outerhtml() if you want the tr